# Не работает функция SeriesSum(n)

Tags: javascript

Функция возвращает строку в формате "х.хх". Для этого складывает 
последовательность чисел вот так:
1 + 1/4 + 1/7 + 1/10 + 1/13 + 1/16 +... n-раз,
каждый раз увеличивая делитель на 3.
Если на вход поступает 0 или не число, или дробное число, то возвращается "0.00"
Вот набросил:

```
function SeriesSum(n){
    if (n > 0){
        var result = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= (n * 3) + 1; i + 3){
            result += (1 / i);
        }
    } else {
        return "0.00";
    }
    return +Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (var i = 1; i <= (n * 3) + 1;` **i = i + 3**`){`

Cкладывать оно будет `n + 1`, а не `n` раз.

```
return result.toFixed(2);
```